# Kernel Panic and Apt Failing to Update Kernel After

Tags: linux, apt, kernel-panic

- **Host OS**: macOS Sonoma 14.1
- **Hypervisor**: Parallels 19.1.0 (54729)
- **Guest OS**: Kali 6.1.0

I have a Kali Linux VM that I run on Parallels that I use to do Hack The Box, CTFs, etc. Usually once a month, I run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. The upgrade was taking a little longer than usual, and I think the reason was it because it was trying to upgrade the kernel to 6.5.0. Right at the end as the upgrade finished, I noticed some installation errors relating to the packages for the new kernel (didn't get an screenshots unfortunately). I wasn't really sure what to make of them, so I restarted.

This led to a kernel panic. I ran into something like this before when Parallels Tools forced a restart during an upgrade. So I booted into the older kernel (6.1.0), confirmed with `uname -r` that I was on 6.1.0, and listed out the installed kernels with `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` and saw:

[image: Installed Kernels]

I tried to remove the 6.5.0 kernel which I assume was corrupted using `sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64`. It failed, and I noticed the error was **very** similar to the one I saw when the initial upgrade failed:

[image: Apt Remove Failure]

I wasn't sure what to make of these errors, but I checked out the log file (seen in the second screenshot) and saw:

```
DKMS make.log for parallels-tools-19.0.0.54570 for kernel 6.5.0-kali3-amd64 (x86_64)

Mon Oct 30 09:38:09 PM EDT 2023

Will use compiler CC="gcc-13".

Compiler version "gcc-13 (Debian 13.2.0-4) 13.2.0"

cd prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg && make CC=gcc-13

make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add '+' to parent make rule.

make[1]: Entering directory '/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg'

1: /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build

2: /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg

3: 20231030

4: 1.10.2

Start compile prl_tg...

make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg SRCROOT=/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg CC=gcc-13 modules

make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64'

1: /lib/modules/6.5.0-kali3-amd64/build

2: /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg

3: 20231030
4: 1.10.2

CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg.o

CC [M] /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_call.o

In file included from /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_common.h:25,

from /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_call.c:11:

/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_call.c: In function ‘tg_req_map_user_pages’:

/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_compat.h:63:17: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages’

63 | get_user_pages(_1, _2, (_3) ? FOLL_WRITE : 0, _4, _5)

| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_call.c:126:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘prl_get_user_pages’

126 | got = prl_get_user_pages(

| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/include/linux/scatterlist.h:8,

from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/include/linux/dmapool.h:14,

from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/include/linux/pci.h:1621,

from /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_call.c:7:

/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/include/linux/mm.h:2430:6: note: declared here

2430 | long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,

| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/scripts/Makefile.build:248: /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg_call.o] Error 1

make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/Makefile:2059: /var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg] Error 2

make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-common/Makefile:246: __sub-make] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-kali3-amd64'

make[1]: *** [Makefile:44: prl_tg] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/parallels-tools/19.0.0.54570/build/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg'

make: *** [Makefile.kmods:48: compile] Error 2
```

I didn't really know what any of this meant. I'm under the assumption that Parallels Tools was trying to compile the kernel, but there was some sort of error. So I decided to try and uninstall Parallels Tools. This was easier said than done but I eventually got it uninstalled. Then I tried to remove the 6.5.0 kernel again which worked:

[image: Apt Remove Success]

I ran `update-grub2` and rebooted. Everything went fine, and I tried to upgrade again to see if 6.5.0 would install correctly. But, the new kernel was not pulled in an installed. In fact, apt seemed to be under the impression that 6.1.0 was the most up to date kernel (it said as much in its output). I ran `apt show linux-image-6.5.0-kali3-amd64` and it returned all the info about the package. So it seems apt is aware of the new kernel, but not that it is the newest and should be pulled in. I wasn't sure why this was happening, and I tried to do some research but I wasn't sure what to Google. So I have a few questions:

Why did the kernel panic occur initially?

Did I take the right steps to fix it? Is there anything else I should have done?

Why won't the new kernel install and how can fix it?

I'm by no means a Linux expert, so I want to understand how to handle these issues, like kernel panics, in the future without panic Googling and just running random commands. Definitely need to build some more of that sys admin type knowledge.

Comment: Try reverting to or staying with Kernel 6.1.0 as that is the kernel for Kali Virtual Machine 2023.4.  Posted from one Kali VM and checked also the other Kali VM

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing. I have no problem staying on that kernel version. I was just more worried about down the line if I needed/wanted to update. I was concerned I had broke something as I was trying to fix the kernel panic. Speaking of which, any idea why it might have happened?